# mschart horizontal scroll causing unwanted chart area width change

Tags: c#, scroll, width, mschart, flicker

When I scroll horizontally a zoomed mschart I see an ugly chart area flicker (right border), caused by unwanted change of its width (this is due to variable scaling of the chart during horizontal scrolling).
Any ideas how to improve that?

Code example:

```
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
int k = 0;
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
chart1.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.IsUserEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.ScrollBar.IsPositionedInside = true;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollMinSizeType =DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.ScaleView.SmallScrollSizeType = DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorY.Interval = 0.1;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.Interval = 5.0;
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm:ss";
chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].CursorX.IntervalType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Seconds;
for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) 
{if (i < 200 ){k=i/10;} else if(i<400){k=20;}else{k=(600-i)/10;}; chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(zeroTime.AddSeconds(i * 5), 0 - k);}
```

Comment: No code? How are we supposed to help?

Comment: OK. Code is available now. Are you ready to help, zeFrenchy?

Answer (score 0):

The resizing of the chart can be influenced by the `InnerPlotPosition` property of the chart area. The default here is `InnerPlotPosition.Auto` set to `true` and this leads to the width change.

The chart width change can be stopped by switching to manual mode:

```
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].InnerPlotPosition.Auto = false;
// optional:
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].InnerPlotPosition.X = 0; // all values are percentage
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].InnerPlotPosition.Y = 0;
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].InnerPlotPosition.Height = 100; 
this.chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].InnerPlotPosition.Width = 100;
```